# Zurb foundation 6.4.3 6.4 topbar menu classes expanded menu-centered not working

Tags: zurb-foundation, navigationbar

For testing, I cloned a site that I built with Foundation 6.3.1 to another folder where I have 6.4.3 installed. Everything seems to display properly, I'm using the float mode.

Anyway, in 6.3.1 I used a couple of classes to style my topbar: `expanded` and `menu-centered`.

I was reading in the docs, from what I understand, you have to include `@menu-expand;` and `@menu-align;`.

Anyway, I tried this and 6.4.3 still just blows out my topbar.

I've posted 2 links here, both have the same HTML and CSS code for comparison.

See this version first - be sure to shrink your browser until you see the mobile menu and click it as well.

[Foundation 6.3.1 Version on CodePen](https://codepen.io/floridapctech1/pen/RLPYdy)  (works fine)

```
<!-- html -->
      <div class="row top-row-wrapper">
    <div class="top-bar menu-centered"> <!-- menu-centered -->
        <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="my-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
            <button class="menu-icon center" type="button" data-toggle="my-menu" data-responsive-toggle="my-menu"></button>
            <div class="title-bar-title menu-left">MENU</div>

          </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="top-bar" id="my-menu">  
        <div class="top-bar-right">
          <ul class="menu expanded menu-centered" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">        
            <li><a class="home-link" href="/">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="/simmental-sires/">SIRES</a></li>
            <li><a href="/simmental-donors/">DONORS</a></li>
            <li><a href="/simmental-bulls-for-sale/">BULLS</a></li>
            <li><a href="/simmental-heifers-for-sale/">HEIFERS</a></li>
            <li><a href="/bull-care/">BULL&nbsp;CARE</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact/">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>



/*SCSS*/
    $menu-margin: 0rem;
    $menu-margin-nested: 1rem;
    $menu-item-padding: 1rem;
    $menu-icon-spacing: 1.25rem;

    $topbar-padding: 0;
    $topbar-title-spacing: 0rem 1rem 0rem 0;
    $topbar-input-width: 200px;
    $topbar-unstack-breakpoint: medium;


    .top-bar ul.menu li {  
      padding-left:.5em;
      padding-right:.5em;
    }

    .top-bar ul.menu li a {  
      border:1px solid blue;  
    }

    .top-bar-right ul.menu li {  
      white-space:nowrap;  
    }
```

[Foundation 6.4.3 Version on CodePen](https://codepen.io/floridapctech1/pen/jGPeON) (same code, but notice expanded and menu-centered fail to work and the mobile menu goes bonkers). How to make the 6.4.3 version functional like the 6.3.1 version?

On a side note: I love testing out little snippets on Codepen, however, I can't figure out if it is possible to add / modify the app.scss that it uses in order to add do things like comment out includes (such as foundation-flex-grid / or add includes such as `@include menu-expand;`.